# What video switching application is used for Apple's Keynotes?

Tags: video

I know apple uses keynote for the presentation software for its keynotes, but I can't figure out what they use for their video switching for picture-in-picture display.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably using some kind of a live switcher for that rather than software, but there is no real way to tell what they would be using.  To keep quality in live environments still generally requires using specialized hardware though.